# What is a coarse histogram?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I'm reading the paper [Shape Context: A new descriptor for shape matching and object orientation](http://digital.cs.usu.edu/~xqi/Teaching/CS5650F03/FinalProject/ShapeDescriptor.Belongie.00.pdf). In section 3 it reads:

> For a point P on the shape, we compute a coarse histogram of the relative coordinates of the remaining N-1 points. This histogram is defined to be the *shape context* of P. The reference orientation for the coordinate system can be absolute or relative to a given axis. In this paper we will assume and absolute reference orientation, i.e. angles measured relative to the positive x-axis. The descriptor should be more sensitive to differences in nearby pixels. We thus propose the use of log-polar coordinate system.

What is a coarse histogram? I'm familiar with the color histogram of an image, which has all the colors in the image as the x-axis and the y-axis are the number of pixels of that color. That's obviously not the sort of histogram they are talking about. After all, you can't make a histogram like that relative to a point.

What's the x-axis and y-axis of the proposed histogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the description of Figure 1, you can see items e, f, and g.  These are the what the paper calls coarse histograms.  Further below your quoted text, the histogram axes are defined as

```
12 equally spaced angles bins and 5 equally spaced log-radius bins.
```

In Figure 1, you can see log r for the y-axis and theta for the x-axis.  Given that they are plotting 12 and 5, is probably why they use the word 'coarse', there's not that many samples.

Comment: I looked at Figure 1, however I didn't get items e, f and g. They didn't look like what I expected a histogram to be. I expected y-axis to be the accumulated value and the x-axis the item you're accumulating. However, log r and theta, together describe a point in space. Upon further analysis I think the color is the value. So it's actually a 3D graph. The color is the accumulated value. The accumulated item is a range of r and theta. If that's the case, I think I get it now.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that bit, but you've figured it out.  The paper does say `(Dark=Large value.)` in the Figure 1 description.